# How many elements of order 6 are there in an abelian non cyclic group of order 18

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

> Given $G$ an abelian non cyclic group of order $18$.
> Find how many elements of order $6$ there are in $G$.

**Found my mistake thanks to Derek Holt's comment.

Leaving here the proof if anyone else might get stuck:)**

We know that $G$ isn't cyclic so there aren't elements of order $18$ in $G$. Therefore all the elements in $G$ are of orders $\{1,2,3,6,9\}$, and only $e$ has order $1$.
From Sylow theorem, There is exactly one $3$-sylow group, so there are 8 elements of orders $3$ or $9$, and the number of $2$-sylow groups is $1$ because $G$ is abelian.
Now we get that we are left with $18-8-1-1=8$ elements of order 6.

Comment: The group is abelian so all subgroups are normal, and the number of Sylow 2-subgroups must be $1$.

Comment: you right! don't know how I missed that.